# Update ng-style width after resize

Tags: javascript, angular

How can i update elements width from angular directive every time when window is resizing ?

Now its bind only one time.

DIRECTIVE

```
function calculateGameWidth () {    
     scope.responsiveGameWidth = Math.floor(( window.innerWidth - 22 ) / Math.floor(( window.innerWidth - 22 ) / 232 )) - 6;
     return scope.responsiveGameWidth;
} 

calculateGameWidth();

//On resize
window.onresize = function () {
    calculateGameWidth();
}
```

HTML

```
<li ng-style="{width: responsiveGameWidth+'px'}"></li>
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561615/css-update-on-resize-with-angularjs  duplicate?

Comment: Already not ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing scope updates outside the angular cycle.

You can fix this with

```
function calculateGameWidth () {    
     scope.responsiveGameWidth = Math.floor(( window.innerWidth - 22 ) / Math.floor(( window.innerWidth - 22 ) / 232 )) - 6;
     scope.$apply();
}
```

And use your variable, not function

```
<li ng-style="{width: responsiveGameWidth+'px'}"></li>
```

Comment: see edit - you are calling the function but dont need to in html